# Google maps KML layer initial zoom and centre

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have an existing map on a web page that is zoomed and centred properly using the following script segment:
      var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: 43.57023, lng: -79.48676 },
      zoom: 12
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

I then add the kml layer using:
    var myLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ url: "" });
    myLayer.setMap(map);

This has been working for the last year. However I had to update the kml file to include a wider area. The new kml file works but the new zoom and centre locations aren't being respected.

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
  center: { lat: 48.0, lng: -89.0 },
  zoom: 4
```

});

Instead the map is zoomed out so I see 3 complete Earths plus a bit on each side and the centre is way above the North Pole. You can see the two different results at http://www.a711lions.ca/recycleforsight/locationmap.html and http://www.a711lions.ca/recycleforsight/locationmap2.html.

I have read that I can use a layer.preserveViewport setting to overcome this, but I'm trying to understand why it is even happening. AFAICT the points are all in Canada (they certainly don't show up in the triple-Earth view as being anywhere else) so why is the KML layer so huge?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your KML file contains a bad point:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Dr. Sibbald</name>
    <description><![CDATA[<br><b>Address:</b> Applewood Shopping Ctre, Suite 210, 1077 N. Service Rd<br><b>City:</b> Mississauga<br><b>Postal Code:</b> L5R 2X5<br><b>Telephone:</b> (905)273-9009<br><b>Sponsoring Club:</b> Mississauga Credit Valley Lions Club]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-3.0,90.0,0.0</coordinates>
    </Point>
    <!-- ... -->
</Placemark>
```

It located at the North Pole.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found it yesterday after doing a sanity check on the coordinates using regexes. Still, it shouldn't have resulted in such bizarre behaviour. That seems to prohibit marking Santa's workshop.  :)

If I'd placed it in a nonsense location, like 91 degrees North, then I'd expect it to be ignored or maybe flagged as "off the Earth". If it's in a legal location, it should be mapped.

Comment: If you have a point at the north pole, the map will display it (zooming out to include it), and 90 degrees is problematic with the Mercator projection used on Google maps.

Comment: A point which seems disproved by by the problem. The location is at the North Pole (90 degrees North) where the longitude is not relevant - -3 degrees is as valid as any other longitude.

The actual zoom was far greater than the whole Earth and there was no marker at the North Pole. In this case, the projection should have used the -3 to display the marker a bit West of the Prime meridian.

Sorry, but I can't really see this as anything other than a bug in Google's code.

Comment: I won't comment on whether it should a bug or not, just that while 90 degrees is physically possible in the real world, latitudes of greater than 85 degrees don't make sense on a Mercator projection (or on Google Maps). And since fixing the "bad" point fixes the problem, it isn't really worth spending any time on (IMO).  You can create an issue in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list), they might accept it.